# Error in Decryption JAVA(Android)

Tags: java, android, encryption

On decryption I'm getting

```
W/System.err(517): javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
```

My code to encrypt and decrypt is below.  I searched the whole forum got the same problem also but couldn't get my code to work.

One more problem or you can say just a curiosity is when I click on the button I can see the encrypted string but pressing button again and again gives me different encrypted string on same inputted text with only last 4 character changing.... which I think will be a problem for getting the same inputted string after decryption.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText ed1, ed2, ed3;
private final char[] PASSWORD = "abcdefghijklmnop".toCharArray();
private byte[] SALT;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   //Setting the SALT to android_id
    SALT = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID).getBytes();
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
}

public void onClick(View v)
{

    String encrypted, decrypted, userpass = ed1.getText().toString().trim();
    encrypted = encrypt(userpass);
    ed2.setText(encrypted);
    decrypted = decrypt(encrypted);
    ed3.setText(decrypted);
}

public String encrypt(String original)
{

    SecretKeyFactory secretKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    SecretKey key = secretKey.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD));
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT,20));
    String encrypted = cipher.doFinal(original.getBytes("UTF-8")).toString();
    return encrypted;
}

public String decrypt(String original)
{

    SecretKeyFactory secretKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    SecretKey key = secretKey.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD));
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT,10));
    String decrypted = cipher.doFinal(original.getBytes("UTF-8")).toString();
    return decrypted;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cipher.doFinal(byte[])` returns a `byte[]` not a `String`. The way the code is currently you are storing the return value of `Object.toString()` which for a `byte[]` is not very meaningful, and does not show it's contents. If you want to store the byte array as a String you'll need to encode it first. The recommend method of doing this is Base64 , but a hex String can work as well but will not be as compact as Base64.

If you just wanted to view the contents of the `byte[]` for debugging purposes you can use `Arrays.toString(byte[])` to see how the contents change. Though even for debugging, I would think looking at a Base64 or hex string would be easier.

In your decrypt method, you'll need to decode the input String back in to a `byte[]` before decrypting it, the resulting byte array from `Cipher.doFinal(byte[])` on the decrypt side can then be interpreted as UTF-8 using `new String(result, "UTF-8")`.

Comment: Thanks for the help now I know where I was going wrong in decrypting string.

Answer (score 0):

try getBytes("UTF-8") for your salt